# Destroy not called on TabPage child view model

Tags: prism

My main page has DevExpress `TabPage` control (similar to Xamarin Forms `TabbedPage`), it looks something like this:

```
<dxn:TabPage>
    <dxn:TabPageItem>
         <NavigationPage Title="Page1">
              <x:Arguments>
                   <local:Page1/>
              </x:Arguments>
         </NavigationPage>
         <NavigationPage Title="Page2">
              <x:Arguments>
                   <local:Page2/>
              </x:Arguments>
         </NavigationPage>
    </dxn:TabPageItem>
</dxn:TabPage>
```

When I logout from my app I use navigation like this:

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync( "/LoginPage" );
```

Destroy method in `MainPageViewModel` is called, but not called on any of child view models e.g `Page1`, `Page2` etc. I've added `IDestructible` interface to each child page.

Is this a bug or by design or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In case of *Xamarin.Forms* the [`DestructibleRegionBehavior`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/7b8b6c36e80ca78d484a9a0a34193e71dce3ed33/src/Forms/Prism.Forms.Regions/Regions/Behaviors/DestructibleRegionBehavior.cs) calls `Destroy` on views that are removed from a region. It does not consider child views. Consequently, the answer is yes, this is the current behavior and I guess it is by design, since Prism does not support every use-case. If you need this functionality, you could implement your own region behavior based on the original one. If your view hierarchy is fixed, it might even be easier to create a specialzed behavior. You could also consider creating a special region adapter for e.g. the `TabPage` if there is no need to reuse or generalize it.

---

The support for `IDestructible` in *WPF* was added with [Prism 7.2.0.1367](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.2.0.1367), as you can see in this [pull request 1709](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1709/files). The previous statement applies to this behavior, too, it is essentially the same. You could extend it to traverse the child views using the [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=net-5.0) or another approach that fits your requirements.

Comment: Thank you thatguy for explanations, will look into IDestructible andVisualTreeHelper.